# Break $content into array when conditions are met

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, symfony4

I have an array with Category names `$categories_array`.
I have a `$content` variable containing a big string (product description)

My intention is to explode `$content` into an array (`$content_array`).
That is easy.
The content also contains category names on it
The problem is as follows:

- category is named `Kids and Baby`

I cant explode by word, as I want to keep the content `kids and baby` in the same array entry.
I also cant query all the time as it would be resource expensive.

What is the best way to achieve something like this:

This is the original $content:

```
$content = "lorem ipsum bla bla bla cat1 bla bla bla kids and baby";
```

This is my categories array:

```
$categories_array = array(
    "cat1",
    "kids and baby",
    "cat3",
    ...
);
```

This is my expected output:

```
$content_array = array(
    "word1",
    "word2",
    "kids and baby",
    "word3"
);
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Is there a list of categories to use?

Comment: I'm finding this a little vague.  Can you fill it out more, with some example inputs, your search code and expected outputs?  Try and add a specific problem/use/case.

Comment: @NigelRen yes we do have a collection of categories.

Comment: @Progrock added more details. I hope it helps

Comment: Sadly this still is a little vague for SO, check how to ask.  Having the category as a seperate search facet outside the description would make your task easier.

Comment: Where do `word1` and `word2` come from?

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't split the content into words. Instead, convert the category into a regular expression that searches for the category with word boundaries `\b` around it.  That will allow you to find `kids and baby` as a single match.

Comment: E.g. `$regex = '/\b' . preg_quote($category) . '\b/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every category search content for that category and replace spaces with a character that doesnt exist in the content.

Then explode conent by spaces (so it will keep category text together).

Later just replace that character back to spaces.

```
<?php

$content = "lorem ipsum bla bla bla cat1 bla bla bla kids and baby";

$categories_array = array(
    "cat1",
    "kids and baby",
    "cat3",
);  

foreach($categories_array as $category) {
  $content = str_replace($category, str_replace(' ', '·', $category), $content);
}

$content_array = explode(' ', $content);

$content_array = array_map(function ($content) {return str_replace('·', ' ', $content);}, $content_array);

var_dump($content_array);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "lorem"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "ipsum"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "cat1"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [9]=>
  string(13) "kids and baby"
}
```

Comment: Really brilliant approach to my view!
Thank you very much.
Will implement and mark as right